# Avoiding overlap with similar regex patterns during tokenization

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

### Background

I've made a couple simple compilers before, but I've never properly addressed this issue:

Say I have a token `LT` which searches the expression `<` and a token `LTEQ` which searches `<=`.
A `LT` would match part of `<=` in this case, and I don't want this.

Other potential examples are:

- `===` vs `==` vs `=`
- `=>` vs `>` vs `=` vs `>=`

Before, what I've done is as follows:

- Order the regular expressions from most specific to least specific
- For each expression match, replace it in the line with an equal-length series of whitespace characters and record the token with its start index (Replacing `||`: `"true || false"` => `"true    false"`)
- Sort the list of tokens by their start index

This is inefficient and only works in regex libraries that allow for a lambda to be passed in to process matches. Naturally I want to improve this.

### The problem

How do I tokenize a string with tokens definitions that overlap as show with `LT` and `LTEQ`?

Possible solutions I've thought of but not tried:

Keeping a map of all used spans of characters and ignore matches within these spans
Only having very simple token definitions and creating more complicated patterns from the simple ones

- `LTEQ` `<=` would be created from `LT` `<` and `EQ` `=`

Comment: *"Order the regular expressions from most specific to least specific"*: did you try a one-for-all regular expression?

Comment: Nope! I never said I'm good at writing compilers, just that I did lol. Thanks for the tip; this way seems easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to tokenise the input in one single sweep. You would create a "monster" regex that would match any token (without regarding context unless absolutely necessary -- that would come later), giving precedence to larger tokens over smaller ones.

Here is an example with a very basic regex just to demonstrate the idea. It is implemented in JavaScript, and it parses a tiny Java-like input:

```js
let input = `
   for (int i = 0; i < 1e+4; i++) {
       int k = i <= n / 2 ? 9.42 : 3.14;
       System.out.println(k);
   }
`;

const regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?(e[-+]?\d+)?|\w+|[<>=]=?|\+[+=]?|-[-=]?|\S/g;
const tokens = input.match(regex);
console.log(tokens);
```

The final `\S` is the "anything else" match, so that this is guaranteed to capture all non-space text. Following this basic tokenisation you'd then possibly create an abstract syntax tree from it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I would have assumed making more comprehensive tokens off the bat would be better, but I'll give this a try